# Using multiple outlets in swift

Tags: swift, label

```
    func lampPressed(Rij: Int, Kolom: Int){
            for var i = 1; i < 3; i++ {
                if status[Rij][i] == "aan" {
                    rij\(Rij)kolom\(i)LBL.text = "Uit"

                }else{

                }
            }   
}
```

I want a easy way to switch between 9 different labelOutlets.
Is there a way to make this happen.
Or else an other way to make this faster

**Update:**
I now have put all my button in a collections:
                    collectionOfButtons[(Rij-1)*3+i].titleLabel?.text = "uit"

and made the fund got from 1 to 3

Comment: how about using an UILabel Array to managed your labels, but you have to write the 2D array index -> 1D array index mapping

Comment: that is a great idea but what is:      2D array index -> 1D array index mapping

Comment: if you create an 3x3 array of UILabels: array =  [labe0, label1, ... label8] and you want to get the label (row = 1, column = 2) then your index would be 
`index = row * 3 + column`

Answer (score 0):

SaiCyli had the right answer.
I have just made a 3x3 array. 
For the index:

```
index = row * 3 + column
```